# Core Data Fetch Very Slow on iPad

Tags: ios, core-data, ipad

I have following Core Data fetch request running on iPad using iOS 4.3.2.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"feed.account.name == %@ AND feed.feedType == %@", accountName,feedType];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" 
                                                               ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

fetchedResultsController=[self createFetchedResultsController:@"RssFeedItem"  predicate:predicate sortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"url",@"headline",@"isRead",@"origin",@"originId",@"date",nil]];


[fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchLimit:500];

[fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];

[fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

return [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

I have approx 688 rows of data in the SQLite database for RssFeedItem table, and less than 100 rows in all other tables.  That query is logged using debug logging as:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.ZURL, t0.ZHEADLINE, t0.ZISREAD, t0.ZORIGIN,           
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 3.3854s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 3.4178s for 688 rows.
```

And it runs very slow (more than 3 seconds).  I  have indexes on all the required search fields and sort fields.  I am assuming maybe the 2 way join is making it slow, but not sure why it would be that slow.  Is there any way to optimize this code or query, or is there something else I should look at?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the lines that are  slowing your query down are

```
 [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray 
 arrayWithObjects:@"url",@"headline",@"isRead",@"origin",@"originId",@"date",nil]];
```

and

```
[fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchLimit:500];
```

I'm curious, why do you need to fetch all those properties (and 500 items) at once?

Comment: Plus, I agree with @McCygnus, reordering your predicate could make a difference.

Comment: I dont think that is the problem because I have other apps with much larger databases and fetching 500 rows is quite fast.  This database is tiny (less then 1000 total rows), so I dont see how it can take 3 seconds.  I can create 500 brand new objects in memory in a few milliseconds.  I can also just enumerate all objects from database very quickly (using no query/predicate, etc.) - it seems generated query is just processed very poorly either by core data or SQLlite.

Comment: But this query isn't just enumerating, or reading indexes, it's actually reading data from disk. (It might be a poor implementation, I'm no fan of CoreData myself.) Still, this query needs to read 500*6 = 3000 strings from disk, create 3000 nsstrings, and populate them with data. Not that trivial, I think.

Answer (score 1):

That seems a bit slow.  I don't know if this will make a huge speed difference, but it should help a little, rework your predicate as:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed.feedType == %@ AND feed.account.name == %@", feedType, accountName];
```

You want to put the cheapest condition first so that the more expensive condition won't have to be checked in all cases.  The join that happens with checking the account name is a lot more expensive.  Also, depending on what the feed type value looks like it, it might be quicker to switch it to be an integer (I'm assuming it's currently a string since it's an object).

Comment: I tried re-arranging predicate as specified above.  But still very slow: 

`CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.ZURL, t0.ZHEADLINE, t0.ZISREAD, t0.ZORIGIN, t0.ZORIGINID, t0.ZDATE FROM ZFEEDITEM t0 JOIN ZFEED t1 ON t0.ZFEED = t1.Z_PK JOIN ZFEEDACCOUNT t2 ON t1.ZACCOUNT = t2.Z_PK WHERE (( t1.ZFEEDTYPE = ? AND  t2.ZNAME = ?) AND  t0.Z_ENT = ?) ORDER BY t0.ZDATE DESC LIMIT 500`

`CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 4.0500s`
`CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 4.0797s for 500 rows.`

Comment: Your predicate is still going to be pretty slow since there's 2 joins happening in it.  You probably need to refactor your model to get a big improvement to it.  Post your model and we might be able to give some suggestions on improving it.  Basically you want to have the values you're checking in the predicate in the entity you're fetching as much as possible and not in a relationship.